# ObservableCollection связать с listView

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

Сначала попробовал сделать так как в инструкции https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding

```
ObservableCollection<Models.TodoItem> todoitem = new ObservableCollection<Models.TodoItem>();
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
base.OnAppearing();
listView.ItemsSource = todoitem;
}
```

Потом попробовал так :) несработала

```
ObservableCollection<Models.TodoItem> todoitem = new ObservableCollection<Models.TodoItem>(await App.Database.GetItemsAsyncB());
listView.ItemsSource = todoitem;
```

Вообще данные из БД в список подгружаются так

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
base.OnAppearing();
listView.ItemsSource = await App.Database.GetItemsAsyncB();
        }
```

после просто в xaml подгружаю данные в список `x:Name="listView"` через `{Binding Name}` и.т.д

Comment: А что возвращает App.Database.GetItemsAsyncB() ? 
Можно код этого метода выложить? И XAML с вашим ListView тоже

Answer (score 0):

Ваш `TodoItem` должен иметь тип доступа `public` и содержать свойство `public string Name {get; set;}`